# bash script behaves differently when run from an SD card or from HD

Tags: bash

I have this command in a bash script:

```
mv audio.mp3 $datadir/$newname
```

where $datadir is a directory created at the beginning of the script:

```
datadir=$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M)
mkdir -p $datadir
```

while the rest if the script is

```
wget -q "$url" -O audio.mp3
poddate=$(stat -c "%y" "audio.mp3"|awk '{print $1"_"$2}'|sed 's/\..*$//')
extmp3=.mp3
seprdr=_
newname=$podname$seprdr$poddate$extmp3
echo -e "${GREEN}\t$newname"
mv audio.mp3 $datadir/$newname
```

the script runs fine when it is located on the hard drive.

Now, if it is run from an SD card, I get the following error:

> cannot move audio.mp3 to a subdirectory of itself

what is wrong?

thanks

Comment: So what are the contents of `$datadir` and `$newname`? That is what matters here if you have path-related problems.

Comment: $datadir is a directory created at the beginning of the script: datadir=$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M)
mkdir -p $datadir
while
poddate=$(stat -c "%y" "audio.mp3"|awk '{print $1"_"$2}'|sed 's/\..*$//')
extmp3=.mp3
seprdr=_
newname=$podname$seprdr$poddate$extmp3
.
Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question above to include that information. We could do it for you but it is better if you do, preserving the line breaks correctly.

Comment: Use `set -x`, or run the script with `bash -x yourscript`, to show the actual commands being run.

Comment: ...also, use more quotes -- `"$datadir/$newname"`, not just `$datadir/$newname`, or you're going to get some fun bugs whenever your filenames contain spaces or glob characters or IFS set to an unusual value, etc.

Comment: ...also, err, WTF is that `stat | awk | sed` mess supposed to actually accomplish? We can almost certainly provide a more robust alternative -- trying to reformat human-readable dates emitted by stat will break as soon as your script is run in a locale with a different date format (and since we don't know your current locale and language settings, we can't tell what it's actually doing *today*)

Comment: Can you show us a complete script rather than snippets? Narrow it down to something that still exhibits the problem. Also, `$datadir` updates once a minute; might your script behave differently depending on whether it already exists?

Comment: Actually, the problem lies within $newname: using mv to just rename the file will give that error. Puzzling is, that when it runs on a hard drive, it's ok, but from a SD card, I got that problem.

Comment: thanks all for your comments. The target name $newname had the ':' character within. Using sed to replace it by '-' solves the issue.